# Map input string to numeric value in launch.json file

Tags: visual-studio-code, config, remote-debugging

I have the following launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Service1",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": "${input:envType}"
            },
            ... 
        },
        ...
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "type": "pickString",
            "id": "envType",
            "description": "Which env do you want to debug?",
            "options": [
              "development",
              "staging",
              "live",
            ],
            "default": "development"
          },
    ]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is: map a specific environment to a port.
For example, I want that if a user select "development" environment, the value that will be printed inside the port field is 5000.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.18.0

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Service1",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "connect": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": "${input:envType}"
      }
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "envType",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember",
      "args": {
        "description": "Which env do you want to debug?",
        "options": [
          ["development", "5000"],
          ["staging", "5100"],
          ["live", "5200"]
        ],
        "default": "5000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is great thanks! I have a follow-up question, is it also possible to give a different name to the debug session? So that if I choose development it says Service1-development on the debug session, so that if I debug 2 environment at the same time I can differentiate

Comment: @GioGio You can add a feature request to add a `"name"` property to the `"presentation"` property of the launch config to be used in the UI, also ask that it supports variable substitution